# How can I get Terminal for scripting on Ubuntu 14.04.2 while being boot directly from USB and not yet been installed on the system HDD?

Tags: boot, usb

I recently installed Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.2 on to a bootable USB so that I can keep it handy anytime I want the Terminal Shell to work on scripting including Sed and AWK. Upon burning the ISO over the USB and booting from it the very first time, I was surprised seeing the option "Try Ubuntu without installing" and yet another option "Install Ubuntu". Didn't it install on my USB from the ISO image that I burnt? I chose to try Ubuntu without installing and a GUI appeared showing keyboard shortcuts to launch some apps but no Terminal. Is my USB stick holding a cut-down version of this beauty? Thanks.

Comment: The USB drive you have is an installation medium, not an installed Ubuntu by itself. The `Try ubuntu without installing` option is **not** a stripped-down version in general, but it does not allow you to save stuff by default. Your terminals are there, they just don't have a shortcut. That's all. Open the dash (the button with the ubuntu logo in the top left) and type "terminal". There you will find it.

Answer (score 1):

The ISO image you burnt on the USB drive is probably an installation package, which intended to install Ubuntu in your system from an external medium (in your case a USB drive, but it could have been a CD/DVD also). The installation package allows you to try Ubuntu before installing, or use Ubuntu occasionally without a permanent installation. See [Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Anyway, how did you attempt to open a terminal? Usual shortcuts are <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F[1-6]</kbd>, for terminal 1 to 6, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to the GUI. Or you can open a terminal window inside the GUI with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Do any of these work for you?